# Constructing a bijection between two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I posted this question previously, but now I think I have part of the solution and just need a bit more guidance to finish the proof:

"For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let {0, 1, 2}$^n$ = { $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ | for all $i \in \mathbb{N}_n, a_i \in$ {0, 1, 2} }. Construct a bijection from {0, 1, 2}$^n$ to {$(A,B) | A,B \subset \mathbb{N}_n$ and $A,B$ are disjoint}."

Firstly, I defined the characteristic function 
$$
\chi(S)=
\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, S \in A\\
 1&\text{if}\, S \in B\\
      2&\text{if}\, S \in (\mathbb{N}_n-A-B)\\
\end{cases}
$$
to map from $\mathbb{N}_n$ to {0,1,2}, where $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}_n$. That is, any particular characteristic function will determine a specific element $(A, B)$ in the set {$(A, B)$}. Then the set $Fun(\mathbb{N}_n$, {0, 1, 2}$)$ contains all characteristic functions, determining the entire set {$(A, B)$}.

At this point, I don't know how to proceed to actually create a bijection from {0, 1, 2}$^n$ to {$(A, B)$}.

Comment: You don't want to define a function whose domain consists of _subsets_ $S$ of $\Bbb N_n$ (note that such subsets $S$ are never elements of $A$ or $B$ or $\Bbb N_n-A-B$). Perhaps you want to define, given disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\Bbb N_n$, a function $\chi(s)$ where $s$ is an _element_ of $\Bbb N_n$, given by $\chi(s)=0$ if $s\in A$ and $\chi(s)=1$ if $s\in B$ and $\chi(s)=2$ otherwise. That will indeed be a bijection between the two given sets (can you confirm it?), although in the reverse direction than has been asked.

Comment: @GregMartin From what I understand, this would only work for {0, 1, 2} but what about all the other cases of {0, 1, 2}$^n$? There seems like a lot of ordered numbers to take care of and I can't figure out a way to assign things like $(1,1)$ or $(2,2)$ to anything.

Comment: Yes, I was imprecise: the $\chi$ I described would be for a single component of the $n$-tuple. Since we want to reverse the bijection anyway, let's start over: given an element $(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ of $\{0,1,2\}^n$, try mapping it to the ordered pair$$\big( \{ k\in\Bbb N_n\colon t_k=0\}, \{ k\in\Bbb N_n\colon t_k=1\} \big).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of pairs of disjoint subsets of $\Bbb N_n$, I will denote $\mathcal{P}$, say. Your function $\chi$ is the right idea: it sort of *is* the bijection, but formally we define a $\chi: \mathcal{P} \to \{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}_n}$ by

$$\forall (A,B) \in \mathcal{P}: \forall x \in \Bbb N_n: \chi((A,B))(x) = 
\begin{cases} 0 & x \in A\\1 & x \in B\\ 2 & x \notin (A \cup B)\end{cases}$$

This makes $\chi((A,B))$ a well-defined member of $\{0,1,2\}^{\Bbb N_n}$ for $(A,B) \in \mathcal{P}$: $A$ and $B$ are disjoint so any $x$ is in exactly one of the cases in the definition of $\chi((A,B))$, and its values are only in $\{0,1,2\}$ on inspection.

Now we can define an inverse function $\Psi: \{0,1,2\}^{\Bbb N_n} \to \mathcal{P}$ such that $$\forall (A,B) \in \mathcal{P}: \Psi(\chi((A,B))) = (A,B)\tag{1}$$ and $$\forall f \in \{0,1,2\}^{\Bbb N_n}: \chi(\Psi(f))=f\tag{2}$$

$$\forall f \in \{0,1,2\}^{\Bbb N_n}: \Psi(f)=\left(f^{-1}[\{0\}], f^{-1}[\{1\}]\right) \in \mathcal{P}$$

where $f^{-1}[\{i\}]=\{x \in \Bbb N_n: f(x)=i\}$ as usual, for $i=0,1$. Disjointness is clear as the value of an $x$ is not *both* $0$ and $1$..

And $(1)$ and $(2)$ is just definition tracing. If you start out with some pair, and define $\chi$ as described, $A$ is exactly the set on which that function is $0$ etc. So $\Psi$ applied to $\chi((A,B))$ gives back the pair $(A,B)$ again.

If you're more familiar with it, you can also give proofs of $\chi$ being injective and surjective. But the same ideas then reoccur.